# Xampp apache server shutdown unexpectedly everytime

Tags: apache, xampp

```
> [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:53:58 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:53:58 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:53:58 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:53:58 PM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:53:58 PM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:53:58 PM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

I changed ports number from 80 & 443 to various number simultaneously like 8080,7882 && 4433,1443. I also reinstall xampp, still its not working. I also change drive from C to another drive for installation purposes. From stackoverflow, almost all the tips I got for apache run, it all has been applied. Now I want to use apache, please help me out.

Comment: Please start Apache from command line as httpd to get more error messages. If you use xampp some messages from early startup do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

The message "XAMPP Unexpected Apache Shutdown Error" is almost always a problem with a blocked port. Therefore, we will change the ports that the program normally uses to connect to your network.